# Displaying HTTPS Page in a UIWebView

Tags: https, uiwebview

I've been searching for hours but can't seem to find an answer to this question.  I have an https site that I'd like to display in a UIWebView.  I can display simple sites like google in the webview but my https site is giving me no joy.  I've tried ASIHTTPREQUEST and everything, but still no luck.  Any help/code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: which site are you trying to load? [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mail.google.com"]]]; seems to work for me.

Comment: Are you getting an error in didFailWithError delegate method from UIWebViewDelegate about the identity of the your https server that cannot be verified?